# How to extend create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Is there a way to extend wonderful `create-react-app` with my own libs, webpack configs, dotfiles, etc., but keep it up to date?

I mean, I want to `eject` it, then polish it to my needs but get the latest updates without big pain, i.e. tracking the repo manually, looking for diffs, copying and pasting and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, actually you can! What you do is that you fork, modify and publish `react-scripts` and refer to those when scaffolding with `create-react-app`:

```
$ create-react-app my-app --scripts-version react-scripts-fork
```

[Here you can read more about `react-scripts`.](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts)

[Here is an article about how to fork and modify `react-scripts` to your own needs.](https://medium.com/@shubheksha/tweaking-configuration-for-react-scripts-in-create-react-app-d91e9d03a42f#.lbob69kua)

It might be that `custom-react-scripts` already has implemented what you are looking for, ie SASS or decorators. [Here is an article about `custom-react-scripts`](https://medium.com/@kitze/configure-create-react-app-without-ejecting-d8450e96196a#.72hdy6qm7) and [here is the package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-react-scripts).